# How to verify that n methods are executing in parallel?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Just for knowledge purposes, how can I verify that n methods are executing in parallel?

```cs
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoSomething(i));

...

void DoSomething(int par)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Test: {par}");
}
```

Is there a test that can assure me that DoSomething isn't executed sequentially (If `Console.WriteLine` isn't a good test, what could be a very simple test function?)

Comment: Make one of tasks run longer, like `if (par == 1) Thread.Sleep(1000); Console.Write....`

Comment: You could try to deliberately create a race condition and see if it happens.

Comment: Why don't you try printing `Current Time` ?

Comment: Why do you want to test this? To ensure that TPL works or to identify problems in `DoSomething`? In any case, .NET Performance counters include metrics of the ThreadPool which you can use to check how many threads are running, eg with Performance Monitor. Also note that `Paraller.For` is a blocking call. You won't be able to check the counters from the same thread.

Comment: Furthermore, how many threads are used depends on a lot of things, including the number of available cores. On a 2-core machine you won't find 10 active threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the methods will definitely be sequential because the .NET console will [synchronize calls from different threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Streams).

You can, however, check the thread ID that is running the method using [Thread.ManagedThreadID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx) or [Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for .NET 4.5)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // first run with default number of threads
        Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoSomething(i));
        Console.ReadLine();

        // now run with fewer threads...
        Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions{ 
                                  MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 
                                }, i => DoSomething(i));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DoSomething(int par)
    {
        int i = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
        // int i = Thread.ManagedThreadId;  -- .NET 4.0 and under
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("Test: "+ par.ToString() + 
                          ", Thread :" + i.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you run this without `Thread.Sleep` you'll notice that only a few threads will be used since the call will complete quickly enough for the thread to be returned to the pool in time to pick up the next job being distributed by the queue.

Adding the sleep will delay the thread (simulating work) long enough that the threadpool will have to source more threads to get the job spun out in a timely manner.

When running any task in parallel it is easy to check that the tasks are, in fact, all running in separate threads.  Whether or not you get a performance benefit, however, will depend on how efficiently those threads can work.  As you've seen, some operations invoke contention on a shared resource (like writing to the console) and can prevent your many threads from operating simultaneously.

Other sources of contention can be, for example, memory allocation - if your threads are all heavily allocating and de-allocating memory then they can end up spending a lot of time waiting for their turn with the memory manager.  This will limit the actual degree of parallelism that you will achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many methods were executing in paralel with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelMethodsCounter
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int _parallelCounter = 0;
        public static int _maxParallelExecutionsCount = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoSomething(i));
            Console.WriteLine("MAX PARALLEL EXECUTIONS: {0}", _maxParallelExecutionsCount);
        }

        public static void DoSomething(int par)
        {
            int currentParallelExecutionsCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref _parallelCounter);
            InterlockedExchangeIfGreaterThan(ref _maxParallelExecutionsCount, currentParallelExecutionsCount, currentParallelExecutionsCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Current parallel executions: {0}", currentParallelExecutionsCount);
            try
            {
                //Do your work here
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref _parallelCounter);
            }
        }

        public static bool InterlockedExchangeIfGreaterThan(ref int location, int comparison, int newValue)
        {
            int initialValue;
            do
            {
                initialValue = location;
                if (initialValue >= comparison) return false;
            }
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location, newValue, initialValue) != initialValue);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But bare in mind that Parallel.For won't try executing too much in parallel since it uses thread pool and it by default uses the number of threads equal to your processor cores number. On my quad-core machine I got usually 2-4 parallel executions with a maximum 5 executions sometimes (but of course there is no strict limit here).

Comment: This "interlocked anything" implementation is so amusingly over-complicated in an attempt to remain lock-free, I just had to give it an upvote for sheer entertainment value. I find the `Interlocked` prefix on the long method name *slightly* misleading as, unlike other, "true" interlocked methods it does not guarantee a memory fence (not that it matters in this particular case), but otherwise this is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you want to do. You can just count them.

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoSomething(i));

...

private static int parallelCounter = 0;
private static object counterLockObject = new Object();
void DoSomething(int par)
{
    int myCounter;
    lock(counterLockObject)
    {
        myCounter = ++parallelCounter;
    }
    try
    {
        // you probably need something that takes more time to
        // see anything executing in parallel
        Console.WriteLine("Current number of parallel threads: {0}", myCounter);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock(counterLockObject)
        {
            parallelCounter--;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why take out a lock when you can `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement`? Then a single `int` field will suffice.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: Choosing the right tool for the job doesn't *really* matter - until it does. There's nothing factually wrong with the answer, but if there's a better way of doing something, it's worth mentioning (and here "better" can be objectively quantified by the number of fields and instructions).

Comment: P.S. Actually, I take that back: there *is* something factually wrong with this answer. Your `parallelCounter++` should be `++parallelCounter`. Otherwise `myCounter` is out by 1.

Comment: Ok, I fix the counter. I don't like interlocked much, because I probably never had a real application for it. You start using interlocked and have to change it to regular locks just the next time you touch the code. But all these is not really the point here. It's just *one* way of counting parallel threads, not even sure if this is what the OP asked for. Implementation details are not that relevant for this. But thanks for the feedback anyway.